# Image App GPS - how does it work

Tags: panasonic-lumix, panasonic, gps

I use Image App on my Android tablet with my Panasonic GX80/GX85 while out on walks to record GPS location data, and wondered if there's anyone out there who could fill in some detail regarding HOW it works?

General notes for the uninitiated:

1. GPS data can only be included on images on the camera SD card once you upload recorded GPS data from the Image App GPS track to the camera.
2. Image APP GPS tracking is on continuously while I'm walking, but I only turn the camera on occasionally when I need to take a picture.
3. I DO understand how GPS data is obtained! (magic obviously :-))

My theory is that Image App makes a time match on pictures taken by the camera with the GPS time recorded by the Image App recorded GPS Track. So presumably there is a margin of error by a minute or so as GPS recording is not continuous?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct in assuming that is uses the time to match to the photos.  The accuracy will be determined by how often you set the app to log your location, so if you need high accuracy without running your battery down really quick (i.e. by logging too often) just use the Log now option whenever you take the camera out to take a photo, this will save the location at that time to match later to the photos.

Cheers
andy

Comment: Thanks Andy. I think Image App only has a default location logging interval. Any ideas what folder these GPX files might be stored in on an Android device? I've had a good nose through the folders but can't seem to find a relevant folder. It would be quite handy to view the raw GPS data!

Comment: You have to record it. Then do an export (I think there are 2 formats available), then pick where you want to export to.

this one also seem to do the trick: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ilyabogdanovich.geotracker

Comment: hi Miguel, sorry I don't have image app, but had a quick look you can change the logging interval in geotagging section, clicking spanner icon displays a slider to control this.  as to where the files are held I cannot answer.  The app that rvpals linked too looks good, and also even just the s-health app built into android will record your journeys which you can then export to gpx file from within the app.

Comment: @Andrewbrough. Thanks for the tip.  I've now found that the recoding interval is once every 5 seconds. Should be accurate enough for my needs!

Comment: @rvpals. Thanks.  I use backcountrynavigator plus l can use Lightroom to produce a track based on the GPS info on the photo EXIF

Comment: Has anyone done any post processing of the GPS info to improve the accuracy of the Geotag? Much like you would a survey. If you have the log file and you have the EXIF GPS data, then it is possible. I am wondering if there are any one out there who has done this? I may find some answers in the uav forums for guys who are drone mapping and looking for alternatives to RTK. If anyone has any insight pass it on :)

Answer (score 1):

To be really specific, that's how I usually tag my photos with GPS on my smart phone.

- I used an app that can record GPS coordinates while I'm walking around. So the exact coordinates from GPS at a specific time point is recorded throughout my journey. It's like "2434.33434,-344.54545, 2017-01-04, 15:05".(As an make up example)
- As I'm taking photos on my camera. Each image would contain EXIF info about the date & time that particular photo is taken. EXIF tag for IMAGE01.JPG would have something like "taken on Jan 4, 2017 time 3:05PM.)
- When I got home, I export the GPS info that was recorded from my smart phone app. Like GPX file. Which is line by line recording of GPS coordinate with timestamps. The GPX file is copied to my PC.
- The image files from my camera is also copied to my PC.
- A program running on my PC can read the GPX file (with coordinates and timestamps), and also read the EXIF tag on my image file IMAGE001.JPG. To know that it matches, and that program updates the EXIF tag with the GPS coordinates (copying from the specific timestamp from GPX file).

Normally, the PC program can allow you to set an offset, like between +/- 1 minutes. The key here is the time stamp recorded from GPS app on your phone, and the timestamp recorded by your camera to the IMAGE file. The program just match the timestampe, and populate the GPS coordinates into your IMAGE file.

Comment: I can also do this in Lightroom. This can also match old photos taken if you have the old GPX track. Need to play around with the +/- offset though as I do not always update my table time to local time when I'm abroad. Annoyingly I have sometimes, but rarely update the time on my camera!